# How to remove participant listener in Twilio in Android

Tags: android, twilio

I set participant listener like this:

```
room?.remoteParticipants?.setListener(object : RemoteParticipant.Listener{ ... })
```

Now at some point I want to remove the listener without removing the participant. I dont see any removeParticipantListener, nor does it allow me to set it to null. I can create new object with overriding all functions of the interface, with empty bodies. I want to avoid this unnecessary new object with so many functions. Is there a ways to simply remove the listener?

Comment: Where you able to find a solution to this?

Comment: @nt95 no. I ended up assigning new interface with empty bodies of all functions